# cordova-camera plugin installed in ios but giving error

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using cordova-camera plugin for ios. It got installed properly but after compilation it gives error in CDVcamera.m file.I am using xcode v5.1.1 and cordova v5.3.3.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULWby.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From XCode, Select Target In Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries you should add ImageIO.framework and CoreGraphics.framework

Comment: i tries adding above framework but still it is giving same error while build

Comment: Kindly give the link of plugin.

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: Yes please share the screenshot.

Comment: i have shared image decription

Comment: CDVCamera.m:152:46: Use of undeclared identifier 'UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString'

Comment: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString was added in iOS 8 so you can't use it with iOS 7.

So kindly upgrade your Xcode and it will also upgrade your iOS version. Latest Xcode is Xcode 7.